# SQL query to display the row of data which combines two tables and does not exists in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

Thanks in advance. I am using a mysql database.

I have three tables `carts`, `courses` and `checks`. I need a row of data which combines carts and courses tables and should not exist in checks table, and I am passing userid = $id from my php function and carts table status = 'Completed'. Here the userid is same for both the tables carts and checks.

I have written this SQL query

```
select c.* 
from carts c 
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                  FROM checks 
                  WHERE checks.order_id = c.order_id 
                  AND c.exam_id = checks.exam_id) 
AND c.userid = $id 
AND c.status ='Completed'
```

But this is not showing the exam name, instead it's showing the exam id because i didn't join the table . so I am slightly confused about that

**Courses** table:

```
id | name    |
1  | PMP     |
2  | CAPM    |
3  | Prince2 |
```

**Carts** table:

```
    id |userid | username | orderid             | exam_id |status
    1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 1       |Completed
    2  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 2       |Completed
    3  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 3       |Completed
    4  |14     | Rakesh   |678g310v671N888M6720 | 3       |Completed
```

**Checks** table :

```
    id |userid | username | orderid             | exam_id |
    1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 1       |
    2  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | 2       |
```

I need a output which combines carts and courses table but the data should not exist in checks table and i am passing userid = $id from my php function and carts table status = 'Completed':

```
1  |13     | Gautham  |437b310v671N888M6720 | Prince2  |Completed
2  |14     | Rakesh   |678g310v671N888M6720 | Prince2  |Completed
```

Comment: I am using Mysql database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.*, cs.*
FROM carts c
LEFT JOIN courses cs ON c.exam_id = cs.id
LEFT JOIN checks ch ON c.userid = ch.userid AND c.exam_id = ch.exam_id
WHERE c.userid = $id AND c.status ='Completed' AND ch.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try it hope you will get your expected out put.
>
> If you have any further query regarding you can fell free knock me.

`SELECT carts.id,carts.userid,carts.username,carts.orderid,carts.exam_id,carts.status,courses.name FROM carts,courses where carts.exam_id = courses.id and carts.status="Completed" and carts.id not in (SELECT exam_id FROM checks WHERE 1)`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM COURSES JOIN CARTS
ON COURSES.ID=CARTS.ID WHERE CARTS.USERID NOT IN
(SELECT USERID FROM FROM CHECKS)
```

Comment: I run this query in phpmyadmin it's not displaying anything